# Combining drop down menu and checkbox in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I'm a beginner and i'm trying to make a login function where I combine a drop down menu and a checkbox. How can I combine these in one window because it currently makes 2 which is annoying. Could I also make it so that I have to check the box in order to click on the login button? Otherwise display something like "You have to check the box"?

```
def login():
 
    root =Tk()
    i=IntVar()
    master = Tk()
    variable = StringVar(master)
    w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "myaccount1", "myacc", "myaccount1", "myaccount2", "Dyrbart konto")
    c = Checkbutton(root, text = "Yes, I want to change account", variable=i)
    w.pack()
    c.pack()
    b = Button(root,text="Login",command=login)
    b.pack()
    root.geometry("400x400+120+120")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are You creating two instances of `Tk`, can't You just use `root` as parent for both widgets? and certainly it is possible to make it display a message

Comment: also why do You have a recursive function? You call login the function that creates a login window with the Button, why is that? shouldn't login do other stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Didn't read question.

> How can I combine these in one window because it currently makes 2
> which is annoying.

You are using duplicate `Tk()`. That's why you're getting two windows. Use one `Tk()` for entirely scripting. So use `master` for every widgets.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def login():        
    master = Tk()
    i=IntVar()
    variable = StringVar(master)
    w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "myaccount1", "myacc", "myaccount1", "myaccount2", "Dyrbart konto")
    c = Checkbutton(master, text = "Yes, I want to change account", variable=i)
    w.pack()
    c.pack()
    b = Button(master,text="Login",command=login)
    b.pack()
    master.geometry("400x400+120+120")
    master.mainloop()
        
login()
```

Screenshot:

[image]